# How to minify css in a folder ASP.net

Tags: css, asp.net, cassette

I have CSS files in a folder and I am planning to minify them usign cassette
So far

I have created a class

```
    public class CSSBundleHelper : IConfiguration<BundleCollection>
    {
        public void Configure(BundleCollection bundles)  
        {
            var BundlePath =      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSSBundleFolder"];
        var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CMSSitesPath"];
        bundles.AddPerSubDirectory<StylesheetBundle>(path);
        }
    }
}
```

- What should I pass for the bundle Collection?
- List item

  Since the CSS files are
  in a folder , do I need to pass them using absolute  path or a
  relative path ?

Since the files are in a folder, i  do not have an Idea how to call to this function and do the bundling . I will be happy  if someone can guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your css files are in one folder, just pass an application-relative path to `bundles.Add(path-to-css-folder)`

Then to use this bundle i.e. in Razor: add `@Bundles.RenderStyleSheets()`

Comment: The thing is those css file wont use by the application it self, used by  other websites .

Comment: Then why not do the bundling from the other websites?

Comment: well cannot do that since its not the requirement .  Thank you